# Gulp Task Say Complete, but does not produce results

Tags: gulp

I have the tasks below to build my app. It's somewhat abridged for web. The output says all the task finished. The **omitted** notify messages all output complete EXCEPT for the Libs task. If I run I separately, all of it works.

I've fiddled with the code, it seems to work, but I'm obviously missing a key fact. Please help.

Gulp File and Output Below:

```
//Gulp File

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    //..
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    gulp.start('libs', 'app', 'styles');
    cb();
});

gulp.task("app", function (cb) {
    gulp.src(['./app/main/app.js', './app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(changed('public/js'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
    cb();
});

gulp.task("styles", function (cb) {
    gulp.src('./resources/sass/app.scss')
        .pipe(changed('public/css'))
        .pipe(sass({...}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(...))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./resources/build/"))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
    cb();
});


gulp.task('publish', function (cb) {
    gulp.src([
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
       //..
        'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./resources/build/js/'));

    cb();
});


gulp.task('libs', ['publish'], function (cb) {
    gulp.src([
        'resources/build/js/angular.js',
        'resources/build/js/**/*.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('libraries.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
    cb();
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del(['resources/build', 'public/js/', 'public/css/'], cb)
});
```

**/**PROBLEM** LIBRARIES.JS does not appear, gulp notify for libs does not work

```
//Output of Gulp (default)
[01:14:05] Using gulpfile ~/dev/ttd/client/gulpfile.js
[01:14:05] Starting 'clean'...
[01:14:05] Finished 'clean' after 5.78 ms
[01:14:05] Starting 'default'...
[01:14:05] Starting 'publish'...
[01:14:05] Finished 'publish' after 11 ms
[01:14:05] Starting 'libs'...
[01:14:05] Finished 'libs' after 2.81 ms
[01:14:05] Starting 'app'...
[01:14:05] Finished 'app' after 3.39 ms
[01:14:05] Starting 'styles'...
[01:14:05] Finished 'styles' after 3.85 ms
[01:14:05] Finished 'default' after 22 ms
[01:14:05] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] App Compiled
[01:14:06] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Styles Compiled

//Output of Gulp libs
[07:26:16] Using gulpfile ~/dev/ttd/client/gulpfile.js
[07:26:16] Starting 'publish'...
[07:26:16] Finished 'publish' after 7.4 ms
[07:26:16] Starting 'libs'...
[07:26:16] Finished 'libs' after 2.71 ms
[07:26:16] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Libs Compiled
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I wonder if `clean` gets run somehow before 'libs'. Could you try to remove `'resources/build'` from your directories to clean list and see if that helps? People are apparently having problems with making Gulp execute tasks synchronously using the official callback recipe, see here for a write-up and an alternative solution: http://schickling.me/synchronous-tasks-gulp/

Comment: These `cb`(callbacks) works?

Comment: No, the callbacks don't. I took an example way too far, learned a lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `gulp.src` does its work asynchronously. You need to return the streams rather than calling `cb` immediately`:

```
//Gulp File

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    //..
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'libs', 'app', 'styles']);

gulp.task("app", ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/main/app.js', './app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(changed('public/js'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task("styles", ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src('./resources/sass/app.scss')
        .pipe(changed('public/css'))
        .pipe(sass({...}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(...))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./resources/build/"))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});


gulp.task('publish', ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
       //..
        'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js'
    ])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./resources/build/js/'));
});


gulp.task('libs', ['clean', 'publish'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'resources/build/js/angular.js',
        'resources/build/js/**/*.js'
    ])
      .pipe(concat('libraries.js'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del(['resources/build', 'public/js/', 'public/css/'], cb)
});
```

Comment: Wow thank you! That one kept me up last night, i figured that return was optional. Still new to the fun of streams. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `gulp` often does not understand the route start at the current directory for a reason that I ignore now (I do not have to apply this solution for my project in Laravel 5.4 for example...).

In my case, I was missing a trailing `.` before my css/js route file, which caused to run `gulp` properly without any output result (no files were created).

So I had to go from this :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var js = require('gulp-uglify');
var css = require('gulp-uglifycss');

var stylesheets = [
    '/css/fabric.css'
];

var scripts = [
    '/js/fabric.js'
];

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src( stylesheets )
        .pipe( concat('fabric.min.css') )
        .pipe( css() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('/dist/css/') );
});
```

To this :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var js = require('gulp-uglify');
var css = require('gulp-uglifycss');

var stylesheets = [
    './css/fabric.css'
];

var scripts = [
    './js/fabric.js'
];

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src( stylesheets )
        .pipe( concat('fabric.min.css') )
        .pipe( css() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('./dist/css/') );
});
```

Hope it helps save some precious time and prevent headaches !